# Como criar uma animação e estrutura-lá para ser reutilizável?

Tags: angular, animação

Eu criei uma animação de um "spinner" igual ao do webwhatsapp, porém esta animação eu criei do modo padrão através do `.scss` e `@keyframes`. Busquei na documentação do angular e verifiquei que existe uma biblioteca para animações, porém sinceramente eu não compreendi muito bem como utilizar a mesma para ter o efeito desejado igual ao que eu fiz com o `.scss`.

Bem atualmente a minha animação está no `.scss` do componente e funcionando a qual é:

```
div {
    display: flex;

    svg {
        animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
        -webkit-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
        -ms-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
        -o-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;

        circle {
            stroke-linecap: round;
            animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
            -webkit-animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
            -ms-animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
            -moz-animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
            -o-animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
        }

        @keyframes rotate {
            100% {
                transform: rotate(360deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes rotate {
            100% {
                transform: rotate(360deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }

        @keyframes dash {
            0% {
                stroke-dasharray: 1, 150; /* 1%, 101% circumference */
                stroke-dashoffset: 0;
            }
            50% {
                stroke-dasharray: 90, 150; /* 70%, 101% circumference */
                stroke-dashoffset: -35; /* 25% circumference */
            }
            100% {
                stroke-dasharray: 90, 150; /* 70%, 101% circumference */
                stroke-dashoffset: -124; /* -99% circumference */
            }
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes dash {
            0% {
                stroke-dasharray: 1, 150; /* 1%, 101% circumference */
                stroke-dashoffset: 0;
            }
            50% {
                stroke-dasharray: 90, 150; /* 70%, 101% circumference */
                stroke-dashoffset: -35; /* 25% circumference */
            }
            100% {
                stroke-dasharray: 90, 150; /* 70%, 101% circumference */
                stroke-dashoffset: -124; /* -99% circumference */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

E este é o que eu tentei fazer com a biblioteca do nativa do angular, porém sem sucesso, nada acontece:

```
<div>
    <svg [@rotate] [style.height]="height" [style.width]="width" viewBox="0 0 44 44">
        <circle
            cx="22"
            cy="22"
            r="20"
            [@dash]
            [ngStyle]="{
                fill: circleFill ? circleFill : 'none',
                stroke: circleStroke ? circleStroke : 'none',
                strokeWidth: circleStrokeWidth ? circleStrokeWidth : '4'
            }"
        ></circle>
    </svg>
</div>


@Component({
    selector: 'app-spinner',
    templateUrl: './spinner.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./spinner.component.scss'],
    animations: [
        trigger('rotate', [
            transition('* => void', [
                style({
                    animation: 'rotate 2s linear infinite',
                }),
                animate(
                    2000,
                    keyframes([
                        style({
                            transform: 'rotate(360deg)',
                        }),
                    ])
                ),
            ]),
        ]),
        trigger('dash', [
            transition('* => void', [
                style({ animation: 'dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite' }),
                animate(
                    1500,
                    keyframes([
                        style({
                            strokeDasharray: '1, 150',
                            strokeDashoffset: 0,
                        }),
                        style({
                            strokeDasharray: '90, 150',
                            strokeDashoffset: -35,
                        }),
                        style({
                            strokeDasharray: '90, 150',
                            strokeDashoffset: -124,
                        }),
                    ])
                ),
            ]),
        ]),
    ],
})
export class SpinnerComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() height = '65px';
    @Input() width = '65px';
    @Input() circleFill = 'none';
    @Input() circleStroke = '#acb9bf8f';
    @Input() circleStrokeWidth = '4';
    @Input() circleStrokeLinecap = 'round';

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Comment: Não ficou muito claro sua dúvida, quer saber como reutilizar a animação que fez com scss é isso?

Comment: @LeAndrade não.. A minha animação a qual está no código do .scss está correta e funcionando, o que eu gostaria de saber é como converter este modelo para o animation do angular.